# Prevent PowerShell from "boxing" program output

Tags: git, powershell, pipe, stdin, msysgit

I'm trying to run the following command in PowerShell:

```
git log --cherry-pick master...branch --format=%h | git cherry-pick -n --stdin
```

`git log` yields a newline-delimited list of commit hashes, which I then want to pass to `git cherry-pick`. However, `git cherry-pick` always complains:

```
'atal: bad revision '12abcdef
```

where `12abcdef` is the first line returned by `git log`. Note, the above is **not** a typo - the output really is mangled like that.

The issue appears to be that PowerShell is transforming the `git log` output into an array of strings and then trying to pipe that through to `git cherry-pick`, which pukes because it doesn't know about PS objects; it just expects raw text from stdin. I'm guessing this is related to the mangled output I'm seeing above, but I'm not sure.

If I run the same command via `cmd.exe` or `git bash`, everything works as expected. I've tried various PS commands on the `git log` output to try to get it to remain raw (`join`, `out-string`, etc.) but nothing has worked.

So, is there a way to tell PowerShell to leave stdout alone (i.e. just let it be "raw"), or am I doing something wrong, or is there a PowerShell-y way I should be doing this that will give me the desired result?

Comment: Pipe the output to `cat -A` instead of `git` and you'll see the problem. DOS line endings. I don't know how to fix that though.

Comment: Personally I would just do `cmd /c 'git log --cherry-pick master...branch --format=%h | git cherry-pick -n --stdin'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `git log --cherry-pick` works like I expect it would, the most PowerShell-like way to do this would probably be something like this:

```
foreach ($cherry in $(git log --cherry-pick master...branch --format=%h)) {
    git cherry-pick -n $cherry
}
```

Or like this:

```
git log --cherry-pick master...branch --format=%h | ForEach-Object {
    git cherry-pick -n $_
}
```

Or if you have to be terse:

```
git log --cherry-pick master...branch --format=%h | % { git cherry-pick -n $_ }
```

I doubt there's a way to do it with pipelines that's very clean because Unix pipelines are character streams while PowerShell pipelines are objects.  You're not going to be able to change how the pipeline operator in PowerShell works.

Comment: "Unix pipelines are character streams while PowerShell pipelines are objects. You're not going to be able to change how the pipeline operator in PowerShell works" - I figured as much, and yes I already know the `Foreach-Object` syntax, I was just wondering if there was something obvious I was missing. Apparently not.